# Retrofit 2 in custom Converter.Factory get wrong type of object

Tags: android, jackson, converters, retrofit2

I get all responces from server wrapped to this object:

```
@Data
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private RestError error;
    private T response;

    @Data
    public static class RestError {
        private int code;
        private String message;
    }
}
```

And all methods in retrofit service look like this:

```
@POST("/transactions/page/{page}")
    Single<RestResponse<TransactionsResponse>> getTransactions(@Body TransactionRequest transactionRequest, @Path("page") int page);


Single<RestResponse<MyDTO1>>
Single<RestResponse<MyDTO2>>
Single<RestResponse<List<MyDTO>>>
```

I want reafactoring code and remove `RestResponse` wrapping. I want move this in one place. I read [this](http://f2prateek.com/2017/04/21/unwrapping-data-with-retrofit-2/) article and rewrite code like this:

1. I change retrofit method retrurn type from `Single<RestResponse<TransactionsResponse>>` to `Single<TransactionsResponse>`
2. I create converter:

public class RestResponseConverter implements Converter {
    private final Converter> delegate;

```
public RestResponseConverter(Converter<ResponseBody, RestResponse<T>> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public T convert(@NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) throws IOException {
    RestResponse<T> restResponse = delegate.convert(responseBody);
    return restResponse.getResponse();
}}
```

3. I create ConverterFactory:

   > ```
   > public class RestResponseConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
   >     @Nullable
   >     @Override
   >     public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
   >         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   >
   >         JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(type, RestResponse.class);
   >
   >         Converter<ResponseBody, RestResponse> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, javaType, annotations);
   >         return new RestResponseConverter(delegate);
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

But in `responseBodyConverter` I wait type is `RestResponse` but receive `TransactionsResponse`